# How can I use the C++11 standard when compiling in CLion

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

I've tried all the usual suggestions. I am also using `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)`, am running on a Mac and have tried both G++ and CLANG.

For example:

Adding any of these to CMakeLists.txt does not work

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

As my test, I've included the code shown below in my main function and the result is always `C++98`

```
    if (__cplusplus == 201703L) {
        std::cout << "C++17\n";
    } else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) {
        std::cout << "C++14\n";
    } else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) {
        std::cout << "C++11\n";
    } else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) {
        std::cout << "C++98\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
    }
```

And here's my build toolchain:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the cmake project is reloaded correctly? In CLion you can reset the cache if it doesn’t happen correctly: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-cache.html

Comment: Try ``set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`` with ``set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)``

Comment: @Dani I have also done this and it does not resolve the issue. For example, when using C++11 syntax to create a vector (e.g.``` std::vector<double> vec = {1,2}```) I get an a compiler error saying "non-aggregate type 'std::vector' cannot be initialized with an initializer list."

Comment: @szppeter I have also done this and it does not resolve the issue. For example, when using C++11 syntax to create a vector (e.g.``` std::vector<double> vec = {1,2}```) I get an a compiler error saying "non-aggregate type 'std::vector' cannot be initialized with an initializer list."

Comment: If you ``set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`` but the compiler is using the old standard, the whole cmake project wouldn't be configured correctly in the first place. There must be some issues in your build tool chain settings in ``File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains``. You can post a screenshot of it.

Comment: @szppeter just added the image.